# How To Group Date by eight two-week periods ~= 4 months and Concatenate Identity Number as prefix for the current year/The next year In Powerquery

Tags: excel, powerquery

I have two challenges, i am trying to display the current year/next year with employeed id as a prefix.Also i wish to  group date eight two-week periods ~= 4 months in powerquery . This is the Challenge

| Name of Participant | empid | Year | Enrollmentid | Term |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| K-MAN | 3005 | 17/09/2022 |  |  |
| HENRY DERK | 3006 | 18/09/2022 |  |  |  |
| FISHER AHMED | 3007 | 17/01/2023 |  |  |
| Chuks Barman | 3008 | 17/02/2023 |  |  |
| Sting Armstrong | 3009 | 17/06/2023 |  |  |
| John Bull | 3010 | 17/09/2023 |  |  |

Expected Outcome:

| Name of Participant | empid | Year | Enrollmentid | Term |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| K-MAN | 3005 | 17/09/2022 | M-3005-2022/2023 | 1st term |
| HENRY DERK | 3006 | 18/09/2022 | M-3006-2022/2023 | 1st term |
| FISHER AHMED | 3007 | 17/01/2023 | M-3007-2023/2024 | 2nd term |
| Chuks Barman | 3008 | 17/02/2023 | M-3008-2023/2024 | 2nd term |
| Sting Armstrong | 3009 | 17/06/2023 | M-3009-2023/2024 | 3rd term |
| John Bull | 3010 | 17/09/2023 | M-3010-2023/2024 | 1st term |

How do i group the date, considering that Ist term start from september, 17th this year  (1st term), Second begins January,17th next year (2nd term) and Third term start from June 17th next year, until it begin another fresh cycle starting from Sepetember 17th and so on and so forth.

I wish this to be automated in powerquery.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Name of Participant", type text}, {"empid", Int64.Type}, {"Year", type date}}),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Enrollmentid", each "M-"& Text.From([empid])& "-"&Text.From(Date.Year([Year]))& "/"&Text.From(Date.Year([Year])+1)),
#"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom", "Term", each
    if Date.DayOfYear([Year]) <17 or Date.DayOfYear([Year]) >259 then "1st term" else
    if Date.DayOfYear([Year]) >16 and Date.DayOfYear([Year])<168 then "2nd term" else
    if Date.DayOfYear([Year]) >167 and Date.DayOfYear([Year])<260 then "3rd term" 
    else null)
in  #"Added Custom1"
```

Comment: Thank you @horseyride, buh, what i need is  from 
September till January16th, display=> 1st term 
From January17th till June16th display=>2nd term 
From June17th   till September 16th display=>3rd term 
September 17th=> 1st term..(Cycle begins)       Example: https://imgur.com/a/phZb5c6

Comment: The  time  is changing every eight two-week periods ~= 4 months

Comment: edited the code to account for terms using Date.DayofYear to parse out the qtr

Comment: Thank you. Other method provided, works buh yours is short and simple

Answer (score 0):

Based on the example dates, it looks like you have fixed start and end dates for terms rather than a repeating 16 week cycle (8x2).

You can determine the term by checking if the **Year** date falls within the term start and end dates.
Create a helper table with dates to determine the term.
The table should have the term start and end dates together with the term as columns.

[image]

Import it using Power Query

Add a custom column that creates a list of dates between each start and end date.

```
=List.Dates([Start Date],Duration.Days( [End Date] - [Start Date] ) + 1,  #duration( 1, 0, 0, 0 ))
```

Expand the list of dates.

[image]

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table3"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Start Date", type date}, {"End Date", type date}, {"Term", type text}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "All Dates", each List.Dates([Start Date],Duration.Days( [End Date] - [Start Date] ) + 1,  #duration( 1, 0, 0, 0 ))),
    #"Expanded All Dates" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Added Custom", "All Dates"),
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Expanded All Dates",{{"All Dates", type date}})
in
    #"Changed Type1"
```

In the main query, merge the helper table joining the **Year** date with the  **All Dates** column.
Expand the table to return the Term.

[image]

```
let
Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Name of Participant", type text}, {"empid", Int64.Type}, {"Year", type date}}),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Enrollmentid", each "M-"& Text.From([empid])& "-"&Text.From(Date.Year([Year]))& "/"&Text.From(Date.Year([Year])+1)),
#"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Added Custom", {"Year"}, Table3, {"All Dates"}, "Table3", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
    #"Expanded Table3" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries", "Table3", {"Term"}, {"Table3.Term"})
in
    #"Expanded Table3"
```

Comment: ..Thank you,Your method works as well. I appreciate